# Restriction on gurobipy problem

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, python, constraint, gurobi

The main problem is the optimization of the filling of a tank, filling it in cheap periods and extracting in expensive periods to sell. I am using Python and gurobipy.

I am not able to model this constraint:
the daily injection should be less than an expression depending on the previous day's filling.

\begin{align}X_i&\le C_i*(\sum_{j=0}^{j=i-1} X_j )\end{align}

I have tried with this expression:

```py
m.addConstrs((x[i]<= C[i]*v1) for i in index)    
v1=sum(x[j] for j in range(1,i-1))
```

But it does not work. Note that $C_i$ is a constant.

Comment: I don't know gurobipy, but tt seems there is 1 opening bracket and two closing brackets in your first line of code. Might be the problem?

Comment: Oh, Sorry and thanks, i have posted it badly, in my real code it was correct the brackets, thats not the issue, but thanks!

Comment: As a general rule, I think it is helpful to include error messages in your question which these two lines of code certainly would provoke.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```py
m.addConstrs(x[i] <= C[i] * sum(x[j] for j in range(i)) for i in index)
```

Python's `range(n)` yields an iterator from `0` to `n-1`. I also think that defining `v1` after the constraint won't work (moreover, `i` ist not known to `v1`) and even if, I think the code becomes more legible if you avoid this.

Comment: Hi thanks very much but i have the error: Key error: 0 with your proposed code.

Comment: Most likely, `x` or `C` are defined different than your formula would suggest. Can you update your question and provide a minimal example, where the error occurs?